# Social events and training days are arranged for all the staff. (already arranged or to be arranged or a regular schedule)?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Social events and training days are arranged for all the staff.

The sentence above means?

1. already finished arrangement
2. They are regular activities arranged for all the the staff.
3. to be arranged (didn't finish arrangement yet)

Comment: Sounds like 2), to me. It can't be 3).

Comment: More context would make it clearer, but it _probably_ means 'the management periodically arrange such events'.

Answer (score -1):

Second one looks like best. It means the regular activity is preparing for all the staff.